How to perform integration testing with Quartz in Xunit
I need to test Quartz Job. The role of the quarts job is to fire Domain Event which changes user balance. Manually it works fine.
The problem in test is that Job does not process Outbox message at all.
ProcessedOnUtc stays null.
Test:
 [Fact]
    public async Task Should_WinAuction_When_BuyoutPrice()
    {
        var user = User.Create(Guid.NewGuid(), "example", "example@.com");
        var userTwo = User.Create(Guid.NewGuid(), "example2", "example2@.com");
        var oldBalance = user.Balance;
        _userRepository.Add(user);
        _userRepository.Add(userTwo);
        await UnitOfWork.SaveChangesAsync();
        var auction = Auction.Create(Guid.NewGuid(), "example", "description", 10m, 11m, DateTime.Now, user.Id);
        _auctionRepository.Add(auction);
        await UnitOfWork.SaveChangesAsync();
        var command = new PlaceBidCommand(11m, userTwo.Id, auction.Id);
        var result = await Sender.Send(command);
        Assert.True(result.IsSuccess);
        var bid = await _bidRepository.GetByIdAsync(result.Data.BidId);
        Assert.NotNull(bid);
        Assert.Equal(userTwo.Id, auction.WinnerId);
        await Task.Delay(5000);
        var updatedUser = DbContext.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == userTwo.Id);
    
        Assert.True(updatedUser.Balance != 10000);
    }

Quartz registration:
Quartz: 
    services.AddQuartz(options =>
    {
        var jobKey = JobKey.Create(nameof(ProcessOutboxMessages));
        options.SchedulerId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        options.SchedulerName = "OutboxMessages";
        options.AddJob<ProcessOutboxMessages>(jobKey)
        .AddTrigger(trigger => trigger.ForJob(jobKey).WithSimpleSchedule(schedule =>
        {
            schedule.WithIntervalInSeconds(1);
            schedule.RepeatForever();
        }));
    });
    services.AddQuartzHostedService(options =>
    {
        options.WaitForJobsToComplete = true;
    });

Job
 public async Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        var messages = await _dbContext.OutboxMessages
            .Where(x => x.ProcessedOnUtc == null)
            .Take(20)
            .ToListAsync();
        foreach (var message in messages)
        {
            IDomainEvent? domainEvent = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IDomainEvent>(message.Content, new JsonSerializerSettings() { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All });
            if (domainEvent == null)
            {
                continue;
            }
            await _publisher.Publish(domainEvent);
            message.ProcessedOnUtc = DateTime.UtcNow;
        }
    
        await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    }


try this.
[Fact]
public async Task Should_WinAuction_When_BuyoutPrice()
{
    // Arrange
    var user = User.Create(Guid.NewGuid(), "example", "example@.com");
    var userTwo = User.Create(Guid.NewGuid(), "example2", "example2@.com");
    _userRepository.Add(user);
    _userRepository.Add(userTwo);
    await UnitOfWork.SaveChangesAsync();

    var auction = Auction.Create(Guid.NewGuid(), "example", "description", 10m, 11m, DateTime.Now, user.Id);
    _auctionRepository.Add(auction);
    await UnitOfWork.SaveChangesAsync();

    var command = new PlaceBidCommand(11m, userTwo.Id, auction.Id);
    var result = await Sender.Send(command);
    Assert.True(result.IsSuccess);

    var bid = await _bidRepository.GetByIdAsync(result.Data.BidId);
    Assert.NotNull(bid);
    Assert.Equal(userTwo.Id, auction.WinnerId);

    // Act
    await TriggerQuartzJobManually();

    // Assert
    var updatedUser = DbContext.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == userTwo.Id);
    Assert.True(updatedUser.Balance != 10000);
}

private async Task TriggerQuartzJobManually()
{
    // Create and start scheduler manually
    ISchedulerFactory schedulerFactory = new StdSchedulerFactory();
    IScheduler scheduler = await schedulerFactory.GetScheduler();
    await scheduler.Start();

    // Define the job and trigger
    var jobDetail = JobBuilder.Create<ProcessOutboxMessages>()
        .WithIdentity("ProcessOutboxMessages")
        .Build();

    var trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
        .WithIdentity("ProcessOutboxMessagesTrigger")
        .StartNow()
        .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x.WithIntervalInSeconds(1).RepeatForever())
        .Build();

    await scheduler.ScheduleJob(jobDetail, trigger);

    // Wait enough time for the job to be triggered and processed
    await Task.Delay(5000);

    // Stop the scheduler
    await scheduler.Shutdown();
}


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
